# PHP Encoded File From Database

Tags: php, database, file, encoding, base64

I would like to know, if any of you had similar problem and, if yes, how did you fixed it?

The problem is about encoded file in the database base. I have to retrieve the file and save it as regular file in system storage.

But I don't really know, why, but I can't decode it. It looks like standard base64, but seems it's actually not.

So part of the file (maybe someone will find out which algorithm is used here):

```
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
```

And here part of the file after base64 decoding:

```
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>\0\0\0\0\0ţ˙˙˙\0\0\0\09\0\0:\0\0;\0\0˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙ěĽÁ\0`\0\0đż\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0jç\0\0bjbjćć\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0.ţ\0í\0\0í\0\0ß\0\0\0\0\0\0&\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0˙˙\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0˙˙\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0˙˙\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0¤\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0<@\0\0\0\0\0\0<@\0\0\0\0\0\0<@\0\08\0\0\0t@\0\0D\0\0\0¸@\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0_M\0\0ě\0\0\0XA\0\0\0\0\0\0XA\0\0\"\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0BL\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0\0\0\0\0DL\0\0$\0\0\0KN\0\0h\0\0łP\0\0n\0\0\0hL\0\0ą\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0hL\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0M\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0@\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0BL\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0BL\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0LA\0\0\0\0\0 ¨ŕIżČ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<@\0\0\0\0\0\0H\0\0`\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0BL\0\0\0\0\0\0/M\0\00\0\0\0_M\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0!Q\0\0\0\0\0\0öI\0\0Đ\0\0\0!Q\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!Q\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0$\0\0zA\0\0\"\0\0\0A\0\0\0\0\0K\0\0\0\0\0\0´A\0\0\0\0\0ČA\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0hL\0\0\0\0\0\0hL\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ĆJ\0\0X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0zA\0\0\0\0\0\0_M\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0VB\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0D:\0\0¸>\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0¸>\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0˙˙˙˙\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Z\0a\0Bc\0z\0n\0i\0k\0 \0n\0r\0 \01\0 \0D\0o\0 \0Z\0a\0r\0z\0d\0z\0e\0n\0i\0a\0 \0n\0r\0 \07\07\0/\02\00\00\07\0 \0B\0u\0r\0m\0i\0s\0t\0r\0z\0a\0 \0G\0m\0i\0n\0y\0 \0B\0r\0w\0i\0n\0ó\0w\0 \0 \0z\0 \0d\0n\0i\0a\0 \01\00\0 \0g\0r\0u\0d\0n\0i\0a\0 \02\00\00\07\0r\0.\0 \0 \0 \0 \0W\0y\0k\0a\0z\0 \0k\0o\0n\0t\0 \0d\0l\0a\0 \0b\0u\0d\0|e\0t\0u\0 \0U\0r\0z\0d\0u\0 \0G\0m\0i\0n\0y\0 \0B\0r\0w\0i\0n\0ó\0w\0 \0 \0 \0A\0.\0 \0W\0y\0k\0a\0z\0 \0k\0o\0n\0t\0\0\01\0.\0 \0 \0K\0o\0n\0t\0a\0 \0b\0i\0l\0a\0n\0s\0o\0w\0e\0 \0\01\03\03\0 \0-\0 \0R\0a\0c\0h\0u\0n\0e\0k\0 \0b\0u\0d\0|e\0t\0u\0\01\03\04\0 \0-\0 \0K\0r\0e\0d\0y\0t\0y\0 \0b\0a\0n\0k\0o\0w\0e\0\01\03\07\0 \0-\0 \0R\0a\0c\0h\0u\0n\0k\0i\0 \0[r\0o\0d\0k\0ó\0w\0 \0f\0u\0n\0d\0u\0s\0z\0y\0 \0p\0o\0m\0o\0c\0o\0w\0y\0c\0h\0\01\04\00\0 \0-\0
```

The hell is that? 
I tried to save encoded data as regular file to my file system.

file_put_contents($path, $data);

Variables names, says all. 
$path is just a path to place where the file will be saved and $data is just an variable with encoded data inside. (Of course I have mime type of the file, so if it is, let's say .doc, path will be "something/something/upload/file.doc")

But what I get is just file with base64's encoded string.

So PHP Community, I need your help!

Comment: So, you're writing the base64 *encoded* data into a file?

Comment: Yes, what's the problem? As far as I know, encoded string, with right format type, saved via file_put_contents (as it saves as default binary strings), should create file without problems.

Comment: Have you tried writing the base64 ***decoded*** content into the file? `file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($data))`

Comment: Oh Sorry my friend. I mean't decoded, not encoded (but yea I even tried encoded data). Same about decoded, I have tried to write decoded string into the file with the same results. :)